# Как правильно маппить результат функции в поле?

Tags: c#

У меня есть две модели: Operator и OperatorDto. Выглядят они вот так:

```
public class Operator : BaseEntity
{
    public string Login { get; protected set; }

    public string Password { get; protected set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public DateTime? PasswordChangeDate { get; protected set; }

    public DateTime? LastLoginDate { get; protected set; }

    public DateTime? BlockDate { get; protected set; }

    public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }

    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
}

public class OperatorDto
{
    [JsonProperty( PropertyName = "id" )]
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty( PropertyName = "login" )]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty( PropertyName = "is_active" )]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty( PropertyName = "blocked_until_date" )]
    public DateTime? BlockedUntilDate { get; set; }
}
```

Задача: вычислить дату разблокировки пользователя. Сейчас я сделал вот так:
Расширил OperatorDto, добавив

```
[JsonIgnore]
public DateTime? BlockDate { get; set; }
```

Дальше в нужных методах я вызываю я получаю время, на которое заблокировали пользователя, а потом складываю время блокировки с этим временем:

```
var currentOperator = await context.PrincipalGet();

var accountLockoutMinutes = SecurityLogic
            .GetSecuritySettings().AccountLockoutMinutes;

currentOperator.BlockedUntilDate = currentOperator.BlockDate + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(
                accountLockoutMinutes );
```

Проблема в том, что это приходится делать в каждом методе, про это можно попросту забыть. Как сделать правильно? Я использую мапстер для маппинга некоторых дто, но я не совсем понимаю, как он мне тут может помочь

update:

Я могу сделать так, но осталось понять, на сколько заблокировали пользователя

```
[JsonProperty( PropertyName = "blocked_until_date" )]
public DateTime? BlockedUntilDate => 
    BlockDate + TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 1 );
```

Comment: Расшифруйте, что храниться в `var` и структуру `SecurityLogic`

Comment: А хотя, не столь важно, что там под капотом. У вас есть сервис который работает с `Operator` и `OperatorDto`? Вынесите это в отдельный сервис по роботе с ними, и используйте, передавая нужные параметры.